# what is the diference between the two statements in File IO

Tags: c, file-io

what is the diference between the two statements and which is the correct one and what should be used?

fp is the file pointer used.

```
if(fp!= '\n')
```

getting  a warning

```
C4047: '!=' : 'FILE *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
```

and

```
if(fp!= NULL)
```

Not getting any warnings.

Full code snippet as follows

```
if(fp!= NULL)
    {
        fgets(mystring,BUFSIZ,fp);
        puts(mystring);
    }
```

Comment: The first one is nonsense.

Comment: fp is a pointer, and '\n' is a char. NULL is a pointer. I agree, it's nonsense to check equality of pointer with something that is not a pointer.

Comment: @yattering Actually `'\n'` has type `int`, see the compiler error. It's not `char`.

Comment: @unwind `\n is int in C but char in C++`, True **?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is the diference between the two statements and which is the correct one and what should be used?

About the difference:
`fp != '\n'` tries to compare a pointer with an integer. This is meaningless.
`fp != NULL` checks whether `fp` is a null pointer. This is a sensible thing to do.

About which is the correct one:
This question assumes that one of them actually is correct. (But `fp != '\n'` is definitely incorrect.)

About what should be used:
That depends on what you're trying to do.

This code:

```
fgets(mystring,BUFSIZ,fp);
puts(mystring);
```

is also buggy because you're ignoring the return value of `fgets`, which would tell you whether `fgets` succeeded and hence whether `mystring` was set to a valid string.

Answer (score 1):

`'\n'` is `int` type in `C` and you are comparing it with FILE pointer  `fp` that must be declared as `FILE* fp` in your code. So this line is `if(fp!= '\n')`  wrong and meaning less. comparing `FILE*` with `int`.

Correct is this:

`if(fp!= NULL)` checks whether `fp` points to a valid file of not.

```
fp = fopen("filename","r");  
:
:
if(fp!= NULL)
{   // if file open successfully  
    fgets(mystring,BUFSIZ,fp);
    puts(mystring);
}
```

In `fp = fopen("filename","r");` if function [`fopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/fopen.html) fails to open a file it returns NULL.

Because in code `fgets` is used that why i user `"r"` mode..